# Remove duplicate rows in table and update duplicated rows id with minimum ID in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I have a `User` table to store unique users, unfortunately something went wrong in my code and the same user kept inserted into table when user update profile.

For instance, User `John Doe` was created multiple times and the ID is 1, 2, 3 and 4. In table `Order` the same person placed multiple orders and `UID` refers to the user in table `User` and UID 1 and 4 both refers to John Doe.

I am trying to

1. Remove duplicates in `User`
2. Keep the minimum `UID` in `Order` if duplicate User ID are used in `Order`. For example both UID 1 and 4 are used in `Order`, I want to update 4 to 1.

Table `User`:

```
+----+------+-----+
| ID | Name | Gender |
+----+------+-----+
| 1  | John Doe | M  |
| 2  | John Doe | M  |
| 3  | John Doe | M  |
| 4  | John Doe | M  |
+----+------+-----+
```

Table `Order`:

```
+----+----+------+-----+
|ID  | UID | BILLING_ADDR | STATE |
+----+----+------+-----+
|1   | 1  | XXX | XX  |
|2   | 4  | XXX | XX  |
|3   | 4  | XXX | XX  |
|4   | 4  | XXX | XX  |
+----+----+------+-----+
```

To find the duplicates I have:

```
SELECT Name, count(1) 
FROM User 
GROUP BY Name
HAVING count(1) > 1 
ORDER BY count(1) DESC;
```

To remove duplicates I have:

```
DELETE FROM `User` 
  WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT MIN(ID) FROM User 
        GROUP BY Name
    ) 
  );
```

**Expected** Table `User` and `Order`:

```
+----+------+-----+
| ID | Name | Gender |
+----+------+-----+
| 1  | John Doe | M  |
+----+------+-----+

+----+----+------+-----+
|ID  | UID | BILLING_ADDR | STATE |
+----+----+------+-----+
|1   | 1  | XXX | XX  |
|2   | 1  | XXX | XX  |
|3   | 1  | XXX | XX  |
|4   | 1  | XXX | XX  |
+----+----+------+-----+
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to update the UID in table `Order`, can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Those dreaded backticks won't work in Postgres - are you sure you are using that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks so much for pointing it out. I am not familiar with Postgres and the query was my intent to do and haven't tested/run it yet. I was trying to explain my thoughts and show where I get stuck and needs help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole scenario as I would do it (I use temporary tables in order to not mess up my database, but it works even better with permanent tables):

```
-- initial scenario, the two tables:
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE
usr(id,"name",gender)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS (
          SELECT 1,'John Doe','M'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'John Doe','M'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'John Doe','M'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'John Doe','M'
)
;
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE
ord(id,uid,billing_addr,state) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS (
            SELECT 1, 1,'XXX','XX'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 4,'XXX','XX'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 4,'XXX','XX'
  UNION ALL SELECT 4, 4,'XXX','XX'
)
;

-- de-dupe the usr table using an insert.. .select into yet another table:
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE
usr_dedup 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS
WITH
w_rowcount AS (
  SELECT
    id
  , "name"
  , gender
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "name" ORDER BY id) AS rn
  FROM usr
)
SELECT
    id
  , "name"
  , gender
FROM w_rowcount
WHERE rn=1;

-- Using the duped and the deduped usr tables to update the old table:
UPDATE ord SET uid = (
  SELECT
    d.id
  FROM (
         usr u 
    JOIN usr_dedup d USING("name")
  )
  WHERE u.id=ord.uid
);
-- "ord" now contains:
SELECT * FROM ord;
 id | uid | billing_addr | state 
----+-----+--------------+-------
  1 |   1 | XXX          | XX
  2 |   1 | XXX          | XX
  3 |   1 | XXX          | XX
  4 |   1 | XXX          | XX

-- now rename the two usr tables to have the usr table with de-duped records:
ALTER TABLE usr RENAME TO usr_dup;
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE usr_dedup RENAME TO usr;
ALTER TABLE
```

Comment: Hi @marcothesane, thanks for your quries and explaination. The `UPATE ord SET uid = ...` is what I wasn't able to finish by myself. Really appreciate your help!